# How to use "fence_vbox" as fencing device in Virtual Box?

Tags: cluster, virtualbox, fencing

I'm just learning about clustering. And now I'm so curious about fencing device using stonith fence_vbox for Virtual Box. I'm searching for documentation about fence_vbox, but no found specific documentation about how to use it. If you have experience using stonith fence_vbox as fencing device, I'm really apreciate if you want to share with me about how to use it.